# Can't Add Migration in Visual Studio Code for EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build a DotNetCore WebApi in Visual Studio Code with EntityFrameworkCore.

I've been reading a number of tutorials and I always get stuck at the point where it says:

Run `Add-Migration InitialCreate`

I get the following error:

> The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Other tutorials say I should run this command
`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

Which gives me the error:
`No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"`

These are the references in my csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2"/>
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="1.1.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final"/>
```

How can I add a migration?

Comment: Are you running the command in the same directory as the proj file?

Comment: no `dotnet-ef` but `dotnet ef` Also, ensure you're running `dotnet ef` from the directory containing the `project.json`

Comment: @tchelidze `dotnet ef` will call `dotnet-ef`, that's perfectly normal.

Comment: [Last comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4797) may be useful

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, that seems to be correct. command is `dotnet ef` but actual executable is `dotnet-ef`

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I'm running commands via powershell inside VS Code, which is running from my project root folder which contains the csproj

Comment: @tchelidze Yes I was rather confused at that myself initially, but I'm definitely typing 'dotnet ef' even though the error message says 'dotnet -ef'

Comment: Does your proj file contain a `DotNetCliToolReference` entry for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet`?

Comment: @DavidG I just added that now, and after `dotnet restore` it gives me the error `Could not find file project.json`

Comment: Which version of the tools did you install?

Comment: @DavidG 1.1.0-preview4-final, since it seemed the closest similar version to everything else (1.1)

Comment: [That version doesn't exist](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet), try version 1.0.1

Comment: Yep that did it, thanks!. Strange my nuget kept giving me a non-existant version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to use the command line CLI to manage migrations, you need to have the tools as part of your project. Make sure you have something like this in your project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference 
        Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" 
        Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Next from the command line, *make sure you are in the same directory as the `csproj` file* and run this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

Answer (score 3):

to make the "dotnet-ef" command available in Visual Studio Code,Install the dotnet ef tool by running the preceding command.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Adding a migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName
```

try executing

```
dotnet ef database update
```